# Php does not recognize PDO_DBLIB driver

Tags: php, pdo

So I am writting some code so I can access a Microsft SQL Server. The code I am writting is in a Centos 7 machine. I've installed the php mysql and mssql packages but when I run

```
echo "<pre>", print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers()), "</pre>";
```

I get the following output:

```
Array
(
   [0] => mysql
   [1] => pgsql
   [2] => sqlite
)
```

I've restarted the lampp and still got the same result.

I've also edited `php.ini` to include `extension=php_mssql.so`, and restarted lampp and still got the same output.

When I run the pdo script:

```
try
{
    $con = new PDO("dblib:host=".$db_addr.";dbname=".$db_name.";charset=utf8", '".$db_usr."', '".$db_pass."');
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "ERROR: ". $e->getMessage();
    die(); 
}
```

I always get:

```
ERROR: could not find driver
```

I relalise that this needs to be configured in the `php.ini`, but the the drivers that are output are commented out of `php.ini`, hence I am quite confused.

Can someone guide me in the proper direction?

EDIT: I've followed @jap1968 answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315354/pdo-dblib-on-centos-6-x), but I got stuck at where I am now.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315354/pdo-dblib-on-centos-6-x ?

Comment: I've followed that answer and got to where I am. I'll edit my question to include this as well.

Comment: Did the `yum install php-mssql` pull other dependencies? Do you see at least the `mssql` extension after restarting the http server in the output of `phpinfo()`?

Comment: yes, it did, and got no errors, freetds, libzip, php.common. php-pdo, unixODBC. I also see the extension in the output of `phpinfo()`.

Comment: also, i've tried to access the db using `tsql` from the console and managed to have access.

Comment: "Ask" `echo get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');` whether you've edited the right .ini file. (Isn't there a fedora tool to set/unset the httpd modules and php modules?)

Comment: `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini` and this is the .ini I am editing. I don't know about that tool. This is the first time I need to had a driver to php, so I am noobish in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found why this didn't work. I installed my lamp stack using xampp. So I had trouble getting the extra modules.

To fix it I reinstaled an apache server (httpd), mysql (MariaDB) and php and I then managed to add the driver I needed, following @jap1968's answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315354/pdo-dblib-on-centos-6-x).

After the driver is installed CentOS only enables MS SQL Server connections using the console, as default. So when I accessed my script using the browser, I got an Error message saying the server was unavailable.

To have access through the browser you need to use (I ran this with root permissions, also it may take some seconds):

```
# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```