# php mssql linux

Tags: php, sql-server, linux

I have a php file with a mssql connection, which works on windows.

Now I would like to run my php on linux.

I installed unixodbc and msodbcsql.

The server is running RedhatEnterprise 6 and php 5.4

I cant find any description how to connect to a mssql database with linux.

What else do I have to install and configure?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly connect directly to Microsoft SQL Server database from a Linux server, using PHP's PDO system and the dblib driver.

First, install the EPEL repository and then install the php-mssql package.  Then use the following code to set up your connection:

```
$dbhost = "your.db.server";
$dbname = "yourdbname";
$dbuser = "yourdbuser";
$dbpass = "yourdbpassword";

$db = new PDO("dblib:$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

foreach ($db->query("select * from mytable") as $row) {
    echo "{$row['field1]'}<br/>";
}
```

Additional StackOverflow resources on this topic include:

[Connecting to mssql using pdo through php and linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953882/connecting-to-mssql-using-pdo-through-php-and-linux)

[pdo dblib on centos 6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315354/pdo-dblib-on-centos-6-x)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same challenge very recently, and after a lot of head scratching ultimately, I decided to go about things a little differently, as follows.

I set up a Windows machine (it could be a virtual machine) running PHP and Apache to handle the MSSQL requests from the Linux box.

The PHP on Linux uses a CURL command to send a request to Windows, and the response contains the data (compressed).

A little off-beat perhaps, but working well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the modules sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv active.

```
sudo apt-get install php-fpm pcp-cli php-dev php-pear
sudo pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
```

The correct location (on Linux) to put these two lines is in `/etc/php/<version>/mods-available/pdo.ini`
there, add

```
extension=sqlsrv.so
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

Then restart/reload php-fpm or the computer.

Then run ./test.php (where port 2017 is the SQL-server-port)

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$serverName = "localhost,2017";
$connectionOptions = array(
    "database" => "MY_DB_NAME",
    "uid" => "sa",
    "pwd" => "TOP_SECRET"
);

// Establishes the connection
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
if ($conn === false) {
    die(formatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
}

// Select Query
$tsql = "SELECT @@Version AS SQL_VERSION";

// Executes the query
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);

// Error handling
if ($stmt === false) {
    die(formatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
}
?>

<h1> Results : </h1>

<?php
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['SQL_VERSION'] . PHP_EOL;
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);

function formatErrors($errors)
{
    // Display errors
    echo "Error information: <br/>";
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo "SQLSTATE: ". $error['SQLSTATE'] . "<br/>";
        echo "Code: ". $error['code'] . "<br/>";
        echo "Message: ". $error['message'] . "<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

And to query the db with SQL-server [pdo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php):

```
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$database = "";
$port = "1433";
try 
{
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servername,$port;Database=$database;ConnectionPooling=0", $username, $password,
        array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        )
    );
} 
catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    echo ("Error connecting to SQL Server: " . $e->getMessage());
}



 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name = db_name()");
  $stmt->execute();
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
  unset($dbh); unset($stmt);
```

Comment: Since your examples are using the vendor-specific functions prefixed `sqlsrv_`, you shouldn't need to install `pdo_sqlsrv` as well.

Comment: @IMSoP: That's the ms-sample. Added PDO.